# Evernote Python API Display Title of note

Tags: python, api, evernote

I've managed to have to the Evernote Python API work and display notes (using the getNoteContent(noteguid) directive).

But I would just like to display the **title of the note** (not the notebook).

The one that is referred as :

```
note.title = "Test note from EDAMTest.py"
```

When creating a note with **NoteStore.createNote(note)**

I tried a thousand things, never made it work. Searched on the Internet for it, nothing.

And to be honest, the Evernote API doc is lame and outdated.

So please, does someone know how to do it?

Right now, this is how I display the content of the note :

```
note = note_store.getNoteContent(noteguid)
notestr = ET.fromstring(note)
    for child in notestr:
    chose = check,' ',child.tail
    # that's the en-todo checklist type of note...
```

Thank you in advance for any clue or answer!

Answer (score 0):

`getNoteContent` only returns the content of the note. If you use [getNote](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getNote), it returns the [Note](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/Types.html#Struct_Note) object which includes the title of the note.

Comment: Thank you but it says:
DEPRECATED. See getNoteWithResultSpec.

And I really don't know how to make it work

Comment: See `http://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getNoteWithResultSpec`. If you need note title and content, you can set true to NoteResultspec.includeContent (http://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Struct_NoteResultSpec).